# Find threads/scripts associated with a port?

Tags: networking

I'm `ssh`'d into a device and using `nmap localhost`.

I see some ports, whose use I'm unsure about.

Is there a command I can use to find the script associated with a port?

Comment: You can  use netstat -p to show the program associated with a given connection

Comment: You can obtain list of connections via `lsof -i`.

Comment: @RamanSailopal When I run `netstat -p` I get back these values but I don't see any ports `Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path`

Comment: @week When I run `lsof -i` I get back columns `COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME`

Comment: @week ah I think I see it under the name column for example `localhost:35285->localhost:2002 (ESTABLISHED)`

Comment: That's it. To get connections for every user run command under privileged user, eg. `sudo lsof -i`.

Comment: Add -t to the netstat command and you'll see the tcp port also.

Comment: @RamanSailopal thanks, I do see most of my ports with `sudo netstat -p -t`, port `9999` I can see with `lsof -i` but not `netstat`.

Comment: Maybe UDP?  `netstat -p -t -u`

Comment: @week no luck with that either. Want to put the `lsof -i` command as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain list of files associated with connections via `lsof -i`.

```
[nobody@nowhere ~]$ lsof -i
COMMAND     PID  USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
smb.so     3187 nobody    8u  IPv4  608554      0t0  TCP nowhere:52266->192.168.99.253:netbios-ssn (ESTABLISHED)
smb.so     3187 nobody   10u  IPv4  608573      0t0  TCP nowhere:55562->192.168.99.253:microsoft-ds (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: Since the question specifies a port, you can use: `lsof -i:2002` (for example) to limit the output to processes with that port open.

Answer (score -1):

`netstat -leep` should tell you everything.